# Mysql database query not working as expected

Tags: mysql

Why can't I write queries like

```
select * 
from STAFF 
having Salary > avg(salary);
```

in SQL?

PS: to find staff members with a salary = avg salary, I need to write

```
select * 
from STAFF 
having Salary > (select avg(Salary) from STAFF);
```

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @MarcusAdams what do u mean by circular ??

Answer (score 2):

An aggregate may not appear in the `WHERE` clause **unless** it is in a subquery contained in a `HAVING` clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference.

The functions `SUM(),AVG(),MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),etc` are called aggregate functions. Read more [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx).

Example using `WHERE` clause :

```
select *
from staff 
where salary > (select avg(salary) from staff)
```

See example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b2f2/7).

Example using `HAVING` clause :

```
select deptid,COUNT(*) as TotalCount
from staff
group by deptid
having count(*) >= 2
```

See example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08b2f2/6).

**Where can we use having clause:**

`Having` clause specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate. `HAVING` can be used only with the `SELECT` statement. `HAVING` is typically used in a `GROUP BY` clause. When `GROUP BY` is not used, `HAVING` behaves like a `WHERE` clause.

Read more [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx).